# Run update methods of model from another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have `Transaction` and `Debt` models.

```
transaction has_one: :debt
debt belongs_to: :transaction
```

When user create transaction and mark it as debt, `Transaction` model creates `transaction.debt` and in `Debt` model I have all logic for working with debts: run `before_create` and `after_create` methods.

So, I need the same behavior for updating transaction. Can I just run update methods (`before_update` and `after_update`) of `Debt` model from `Transaction` model without any update attributes?

As I understand all update methods, like `update` and `update_attributes` require some attributes for updating.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

You can run specific callback, thanks to ActiveRecord context, like this :

```
transaction.run_callbacks(:update)
```

Comment: Thanks! In my case it will be `self.debt.run_callbacks(:update)`, but there is a problem: in fact in doesn't update debt, it only runs update methods of it. I mean, if I have some debt changes in `before_update`, they won't be saved. Now I see, that my question wasn't clear, but in fact I need to update debt from transaction model, but without any attributes.

Answer (score 0):

If you define the `before_update` and `after_update` callbacks as actual methods then you can call them directly outside of the callbacks.

```
class Debt < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_update :do_before
  after_update :do_after

  def do_before
    # Before update processing
  end

  def do_after
    # After update processing
  end
```

Those callbacks will be called by active record when the debt is updated in the usual way but are also available to you to call from your transaction:

```
self.debt.do_before
self.debt.do_after
```